# Log.d not working in modules?

Tags: android, logcat

In Android Studio 2.3.3. I add new module (**common**) as Android library

so project structure is:

```
MyProject
-app
--src
---main
----java
----MainActivity.java
-common
--src
---main
----java
----StringUtil.java
```

In project **settings.gradle**:

```
include ':app', ':common'
```

In **app/build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':common')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here snippet from **app/MainActivity**:

```
import myproject.customer.BuildConfig;
import myproject.customer.common.StringUtil;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate:");
        StringUtil.urlEncodeQueryString("some_url_to_encode");

    }
```

And here snippent from module: **common/StringUtil**:

```
import myproject.customer.common.BuildConfig;

    public static void urlEncodeQueryString(String urlToEncode) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "urlEncodeQueryString: urlToEncode = " + urlToEncode);
        String urlQueryEncode = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlToEncode);
            URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
            urlQueryEncode = uri.toASCIIString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException | URISyntaxException e) {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

And here logcat output:

```
10-24 18:18:12.407 D/myproject.customer.ui.MainActivity(31646): onCreate:
```

As you can see the MainActivity is logging , but **StringUtil** (from module) is not logging. Message "`urlEncodeQueryString: urlToEncode =`" is not show.

Why?

P.S. If I remove "`if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)`" in **StringUtil** than message is show. But I need this check because message must show only in Debug mode.

Comment: I would put a Log statement right after the method call just to be sure it gets called first.  Maybe the " if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)" is evaluating to false perhaps and that's why it's not logging.

Comment: make sure not to filter the logcat on the wrong process, etc

Comment: In "app" if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)  return true, but in module "common" if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)  return false. Why?:

Comment: Not filters (all is Verbose in logcat)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to check `BuildConfig.DEBUG`.

If you just set your `buildType` to `debuggable false` which is by default done for you for release signed applications, no logs can be read regardless of what their level is (info, debug, warning...)

Example (explicitly setting it, which is not needed):

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "App - Debug"
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, I do not see anything wrong in your code. Probably the problem lies else where. I have been using `BuildConfig` in other classes and it works fine.

Comment: I add "debuggable false" in "release" buildType. But when I start app in "release" mode the log is show! Log.d(TAG, "onCreate_TEST Log"); Why?

Comment: Did you build a Release buildType app? You can do that from `Build -> Generate Signed APK` then selecting release on `Build Type`. Install that on your phone, and have your Android Studio running, you won't see any logs.

Comment: I build Release by gradle (buildType = release). As result I get signed apk. But after install apk in phone the log show! Why?

Comment: Is your phone rooted?

Comment: Also are you sure you are seeing the logs of the release version, not the debug version? To make sure, kill the debug app.

Comment: Not rooted. I try on 2 devices. Same result. On release build the message show in logcat